# pytest fake filesystem and unittest mock interfere

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django, pyfakefs

I have a large pytest suite for a django project which uses plenty of mockers ([unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), [requests-mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/) and [aioresponses](https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses)) and a [fake filesystem](https://pytest-pyfakefs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). I have set up the fake filesystem to use some directories which are required by django:

```
PROJECT_BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
fs.add_real_paths(
    [
        PROJECT_BASE_DIR,
        os.path.dirname(django.__file__),
    ]
)
```

At random, mockers stop working. `AssertionError: Expected 'some_mocked_method' to be called once. Called 0 times.` I recieve no other errors or warnings, just the above message. <s>I cannot reproduce this in a minimal example, since it only occurrs on some executions, not every time. When it happens, the tests freeze and I cannot even wait for the test suite to finish. I run them in parallel with `pytest-xdist` and 8 workers, which might also play a part in the problem.</s> (see EDIT)

I do not even know where to start on this problem. Has anyone experienced something similar when using the combination betweek `unittest.mock` and `pyfakefs`?
Is there any alternative to `pyfakefs`? I could not find anything similar.
Is there any reason why these two would even interfere?

Here are the package versions I'm using

```
pyfakefs==5.3.2
pytest==7.4.3
pytest-django==4.7.0
pytest-mock==3.12.0
pytest-xdist==3.5.0
```

**EDIT**

Finally, I did produce a minimal example: https://github.com/konnerthg/minimal_django_pyfakefs_unittest_mock

Am I missing something very simple and obvious? Or is this a bug?

**EDIT 2**

Here's the output after running pytest in the project linked above. After `pytest -m without_fakefs` (this is a dummy test case which checks that the pytest setup is correct): `2 passed`, as expected.

But after running `pytest -m with_fakefs`, i.e. the exact same test case, but with the `fs` fixture, I receive:

```
___________________________________________________ test_fs_and_mocker[1] ____________________________________________________

client = <django.test.client.Client object at 0x7f1e94f7a850>
fs = <pyfakefs.fake_filesystem.FakeFilesystem object at 0x7f1e94f7bb90>, counter = 1

    @pytest.mark.with_fakefs
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("counter", range(2))
    def test_fs_and_mocker(
        client,
        fs,
        counter,
    ):
        with unittest.mock.patch("mysite.views.foo") as mocker:
            client.get("/foo/")
>           mocker.assert_called()

.../minimal_django_pyfakefs_unittest_mock/mysite/tests/mysite/views_test.py:14: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <MagicMock name='foo' id='139769325143440'>

    def assert_called(self):
        """assert that the mock was called at least once
        """
        if self.call_count == 0:
            msg = ("Expected '%s' to have been called." %
                   (self._mock_name or 'mock'))
>           raise AssertionError(msg)
E           AssertionError: Expected 'foo' to have been called.

/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/mock.py:908: AssertionError

================================================== short test summary info ===================================================
FAILED tests/mysite/views_test.py::test_fs_and_mocker[1] - AssertionError: Expected 'foo' to have been called.
=================================== 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 deselected, 2 warnings in 0.25s ====================================
```

Note that the first case (i.e. the first execution of the same test) always succeeds. If I run it 10 times rather than 2, the first succeeds and the other 9 fail. Moreover, if I run the cases in parallel with `xdist` and 8 workers, the first 8 succeed and everything thereafter fails.

I run Ubuntu 23.04, 64-bit, Kernel Version Linux 6.2.0-36-generic on a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ARH7 with an AMD Ryzen™ 7 6800HS Creator Edition × 16 processor. Python 3.11.4

Comment: It sounds like some sort of race condition, suggesting that there's some sort of interaction between your tests...but without a reproducer, it's impossible to either identify the problem or suggest a possible fix. Does the problem go away completely if you run the tests serially instead of in parallel? What about running them serially but in a [random order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-random-order/)? That can sometimes help identify interactions between tests.

Comment: There could be some interference between `pyfakefs` and `mock` if you are using `mock` to mock filesystem functions, for example [by using mock_open](https://pytest-pyfakefs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#pyfakefs-and-mock-open). As already mentioned by @larsks, I would also try to run it without `xdist` to check if this plays a role.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen this is a good point, but I do not mock any filesystem functions. I should have pointed this out

Comment: @Gerry - that was only a wild guess. It is difficult to say anything definitive without having a reproducible example, but I understand that this is not really possible in your case. I have been using `pyfakefs` with `django` myself in the past, so I know that it can work, but not in that combination. Have you tried to run it without `xdist`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I did produce a minimal example (see edit). It's so simple, I don't know why I could not get it to work earlier. Can you reproduce the bug? It seems so simple and obvious. I am a bit concerned that it might behave like this only on my machine.

Comment: @larsks I had the same suspicion. That there could be some leak within the order of the tests, probably made worse by xdist. But apparently it is much simper than that. See edit. I get the same behavior without xdist and with only 2 test cases

Comment: @Gerry - can't test it now, but I will have a look tonight. Feel free to write an issue in pyfakefs (I'm a maintainer of pyfakefs).

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this - the tests all pass for me. Can you add the pytest output and your environment to the question?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen hmm I am indeed concerned that this could be somehow related to my machine... It is just too odd. See edit

Comment: After some more tries I _could_ reproduce the problem, and I think it is indeed a bug in pyfakefs. The problem has to do with modules dynamically loaded during the test, which are curently removed from `sys.modules` after the test to avoid having patched modules loaded. The assumption was that they are loaded on next access, but with django's dynamic loading of modules this seems not always to be the case (it seems also to be timing dependent, thus my problems to reproduce it). I have some idea how to fix this, though that may take a bit - will probably only properly get to it at the weekend.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pyfakefs/issues/932).